# How to understand RSA encryption/decryption equation?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

I can understand how *RSA* works and how the public/private keys are generated. However, I am confused on the encryption and decryption equations of *RSA*.

To encrypt the message $m$:
$c = m^e \mod n$

While to decrypt: $m = c^d \mod n$

Why the reminder can be used as the encrypt message and why it can get decrypted? How could the 3 inventors derive the equations?

Could anyone help explain it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way might be to try it with some small numbers.

Comment: inverse of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $n=p\cdot q$ for two primes $p,q$ and $e$ must fulfill $1<e<\phi(n)$ and $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

We also pick $m$ to be coprime to $p,q$

Our $d$  is the multiplicative inverse of $e$ in $\mod \phi(n)$, so $$e \cdot d + k \cdot \phi(n)=1$$
This means that $e \cdot d = -k \cdot \phi(n)+1$, so we can rewrite

$$m^{ed} = m^{-k\cdot \phi(n)+1}=m\cdot m^{-k\cdot \phi(n)}=m\cdot (m^{\phi(n)})^{-k} \mod n$$

Now if $m$ and $n$ were coprime, we could use the Fermat-Euler theorem

$$m^{\phi(n)}=1 \mod n$$ and be done. But we picked $m$ to be coprime to $p,q$, which are the only nontrivial divisors of $n$, so this is given.

At last we have

$$m\cdot (m^{\phi(n)})^{-k}=m \cdot 1^{-k}=m \mod n$$

Overall we have shown

$$m^{ed}=m \mod n$$

Comment: $\bmod \varphi (n)$

Comment: Corrected! Thanks